# Angular 4 ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with observable but not promise

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am experiencing this error when a child component sets text in another component through a shared service. This happens when the child component subscribes to an Observable from the Angular Translation service in its `onInit` hook. However, if I change the observable to a promise (`.toPromise().then(..)` over `.subscribe(..)`, the problem vanishes.

I would like to understand why.

My setup...

root.component.html:

```
<app-page-title>{{ 'STRINGS.loading' | translate }}</app-page-title>
<div>
  <!-- view component rendered here -->
  <router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
</div>
```

page-title.service.ts:

```
getPageTitle() {
  return this.pageTitle;
}
setPageTitle(pageTitle: string) {
  this.pageTitle = pageTitle;
}
```

page-title.component.html:

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="isBack()">
    <div class="page-title-text">
     {{getPageTitle()}}
    </div>
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

view.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Triggers ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError 
  this.translationService.get('VIEW.title').subscribe(pageTitle => this.titleService.setPageTitle(pageTitle));

  // Works
  // this.translationService.get('VIEW.title').toPromise().then(pageTitle => this.titleService.setPageTitle(pageTitle));

}
```

One other thing to note is, this is a SPA. The error only shows up when loading the view.component through javascript by navigating to it through the app. If on the view where this problem presents itself, and I hit refresh, the error does not occur.

I've read a little bit about this behavior here: https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

but I still do not understand why this problem is occurring specifically with an Observable, but not a promise.

Comment: because promise is asynchronous, it's mentioned in the article you linked. If you can reproduce the problem in stackblitz I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

view.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.translationService.get('VIEW.title').subscribe(pageTitle => 
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.titleService.setPageTitle(pageTitle);
     }, 0);
   );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Borad, but can you explain your answer? I'd really like to understand this better. I've already shown one workaround to the problem, and I noticed that similarly, using an async event emitter solves the problem. But it seems like doing it asynchronously should exacerbate the issue rather than mitigate.

Specifically, why is an observable causing a problem, but not a promise.

Comment: Observable returns stream data,values over time but promise returns single value , so if we use promise we will get single value and it will call setPageTitle once after promise resolved,but in case of observable it may return multiple values, so it may happen that angular detection cycle ran before setPageTitle method call, thus it throws error like ExpressionChangedAfterithasbeencheckederror
that's what I know about it